# IconButton does not align with clickable area

Tags: flutter

I have a simple icon button as presented below, for somereason the clickable area do not align with the icon, no matter what I do. tried to run the app on Linux, Web and Android.. all with the same issue.

[image: image below]

```
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(children: [
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.highlight_off,
          size: 70,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ])));
```

A simplified version of what my code looks like:

```
MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
      child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 500,
              height: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 5,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: -40,
              right: 5,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () => {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.highlight_off,
                  size: 70,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    )));
```

Comment: I went around this issue by using ```GestureDetector```, but still can't figure out what is wrong with ```IconButton```.. the code:```GestureDetector(
onTap: () => {print('s')},
child: Icon(
Icons.highlight_off,
size: 70,
color: Colors.red,
),
),```

Comment: did you use a parent widget like stack or position?

Comment: I did use stack and positioned the widget

Comment: can you show us all the code including your stack widget?

Comment: I've add the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

The reason this was happening, your `iconSize` is very big. So, according to this you need to make sure your button itself adjust its size. For that you can use `BoxConstraints` to provide it `minHeight`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Stack(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 500,
                  height: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 5,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: -40,
                  right: 5,
                  child: IconButton(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: 100,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.highlight_off,
                      size: 70,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```